# How to resolve issue with No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header present

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jersey

I have a JAX-RS controller with GET and PUT operations. I also have a front end using react in which I do the below

```
let headers = new Headers();

  headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
  headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

  headers.append('GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS');


    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: "http://localhost:8080/toPing",
        params: {
            name: this.state.name
        },
        headers: headers
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

On doing this, I get a

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/toPing?name='abc'' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

On chrome, when I click on the link that is generated above, I get the response needed, although the link is in the error.

I have tried including the headers in the axios request, but thats no use either.

Is there a way I to solve this?

Comment: You need to send correct response headers from server side response. CORS headers(`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) should be put at server side and not client side. See [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) link for more info.

Answer (score 0):

**Both are response header**

```
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin
   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
```

Well as the error says 'http://localhost:3000' is not allowed to access the resource
from 'http://localhost:8080'. For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from scripts.

So when you made a request to 'http://localhost:8080' from 'http://localhost:3000'
it voilated the cors policy and to make this work server need to tell the browser if response can be shared with the requesting code.

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is a response header to tell that and you have to add it on the response side not on the request.
```

So the response from the server should contain the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
with the origin which are allowed to access resource like below.

> > Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
>
> for more depth knowledge please read 
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS